# Set all rows RowState to ADDED for a given DataTable

Tags: c#, ado.net

I was wondering is there any way to set the RowStatus of all rows belongs to given DataTable in one shot ?

**Background:**
I'm fetching a DataTable from DB, Now I want push the `DataTable` as-is to different database. Now, the problem is , in order to push the `DataTable` to new database using `SqlDataAdapter`.Update method, it requires `RowState` to be `Added` or `Modified`. In my case I have retrieved the data from the db, so all rows will have RowState `Unchanged`.

**Solution**:
Currently I'm updating each row state like below:

```
foreach (DataRow row in MyDataTable.Rows)
{
   row.SetAdded();
}
```

**Is there any better solution where I can set all rows status in one shot at the table level?**

**Alternative Approach**: *[suggested by paul]*

Using `SqlBulkCopy` I can achieve this. But I have the problem with this approach. Once I call `WriteToServer`, how do I know how many records inserted ? One way is subscribe for `SqlRowsCopied` event and set the `mySqlBulkCopy.NotifyAfter = MyDataTable.Rows.Count`, but this is event driven.

**Is there any way to get the number of rows inserted immediately after invoking the** `mySqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer()` ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use bulk copy? As in:

```
using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = 
                "dbo.DestinationTableName";

            try
            {
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(sourceDataTable);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response! I could have, but SqlBulkCopy won't allow row level validation while pushing the record to database. I need to validate while updating a row.

Comment: Validate the rows in memory before calling bulk copy?